# MGWT/ GWT-PhoneGap: How does MGWT Work with Super Dev Mode on GWT 2.7?

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, gwt, mgwt

When using MGWT you can use SuperDevMode very easy as it was explained here: http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/07/mgwt-super-dev-mode.html

gwt.xml config ist:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="mgwt.superdevmode" value="on" />

<set-configuration-property name="mgwt.superdevmode_host" value="http://<yourhost>:<port>" />
```

In the entrypoint function you set:

SuperDevModeUtil.showDevMode();

In eclipse you create a Java Run Configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This works perfect with GWT 2.6.1 but with GWT 2.7 when you tap super dev mode on and hit compile the compiler does not finish.

**How can I make SuperDevMode Running with MGWT and GWT 2.7?**

**Edit: How can I make SuperDevMode running in a GWT-PhoneGap environment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has become much easier. The only thing you need to do with GWT 2.7 is to add the argument 
-superDevMode in your Web Application RunConfiguration, that's it.
You don't need the compile button anymore because the compile is automatically triggered when reloading the browser. Regarding the xsiframe this is the default linker in GWT 2.7. You don`t need to do any steps you posted anymore, only add the argument -superDevMode.

Comment: I manage it to run on desktop browsers but how is it done on mobile in a GWT-PhoneGap environment? The host is on a different computer do I have to use mgwt.superdevmode_host flag? Thank you for help.

Comment: When this issue is fixed it will also work in a PhoneGap environment:https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8938
I will also add a small JavaScript file to gwt-phonegap that will deal with recompilation.

Comment: Will this be part of GWT 2.7?

Comment: Yes, it's planned to be part of GWT 2.7

Comment: Here is the documentation for running SuperDevMode with PhoneGap:
https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/wiki/SuperDevMode-with-PhoneGap